# Swift: Error occurs after upgrading Xcode 7.2 to 8

Tags: swift3, xcode8, eventtrigger

I am currently facing a problem after updating Xcode 7.2 to Xcode 8. 
[Here is the screenshot of the workingspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7H6d.png). Everything worked fine before the update. Did Apple change something in terms of trigger event?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you have code to share with us, please don't post it as image. You can add it to your post and [format it as code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for selectors has changed significantly. Instead of this:

```
Selector(runCalculation())
```

You should use:

```
#selector(runCalculation)
```

For more info on #selector syntax, check out [this post](https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/) from the Swift team.